# Force close when app runs on mobile

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database created using sqlitebrowser which is then copied on to the assets folder (Database size is 248kb). I have code for copying this database in assets folder to android default location. The app works perfectly when i run it on an emulator. But when i run the same app in a mobile device and try to do anything with the database, it shows force close. ie; When i run the app it provides me with the user interface (shows edittxts and buttons). Now when i enter data and click on the button it has to access the database and return the result of the query i have. This works fine in emulator but throws force close in mobile device. (I have only copied the .apk file of my app on the mobile device). What could be d problem?

1. Is it the mismatch of versions of app and mobile device?
2. Is it the database which is not available for the app when it runs on other devices?
3. Or any other reason?

Provide solutions for whatever the problem is? I dont know if logcat will have it logged as the problem occurs only when i run on other device.

Comment: I think you should connect your device with computer as USB debug and see in logcat.

Comment: Is it enough to have the database in assets folder which is then copied on to the default location using code for the app to use or interact with the database?

Comment: typically, that is enough, but like Ketan said, it may be a good idea to hook the mobile to logcat to take a look at the stack trace